# Simple Bluetooth diagnostics app for Windows that accepts connections from Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm experimenting with Bluetooth connections on my Android and I need something on the other end that can respond. I only have one Android, but I could use the Bluetooth radio from my Windows laptop.

Is there a simple Windows app that accepts Bluetooth connections and lets me send text back and forth? Or is there perhaps a better way to do my testing?

---

**Edit:** Trevor solved my issue, but I'll elaborate a bit more for future reference. I added a COM port for incoming connections as follows:

[image]

I opened PuTTY on COM9 and I connected to my computer using the BlueTerm app on Android. I can now see the characters that are being sent.

Comment: Why was my post downvoted and closed as off topic? I want to respect the rules, but I'm not sure why this post is being targeted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a Bluetooth virtual serial port on your Windows machine, and then use a terminal program (e.g. Hyperterminal, Termite, or whatever) to communicate plaintext through that virtual serial port.

For the Android side, you could initially use the BluetoothChat example.

Comment: Excellent! I was about to mention actually that you may need to ensure that the Bluetooth Chat example is compiled to use the SPP UUID. Also, beware of a bug in that example that causes received characters to be corrupted if they're received at anything greater than slow typing speed (I can point you to an answer where I explained this if needed - or have a look at my list of answers.)

Comment: I used the [BlueTerm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.pymasde.blueterm) app during testing, which appears to work like a charm. Your mentioning the SPP UUID also made me realize that I'm using the UUID field wrong in the app I'm working on, so you accidentally saved me a few additional hours.